# iphone camera - use imac webcam instead?

Tags: iphone, camera

Can I not somehow use the built in webcam on my imac to test camera functions in the simulator?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: It's only me speculating, but I think Apple could already be working on this. In the simulator that ships with the iPhone 4 sdk the Camera app is available. However, opening it just shows the camera shutter closed and niching can be done with it. Maybe in a future release it will use the built in iSight of the Mac if it's available?

Comment: +1 for optimism :) and educated speculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, unfortunately.

Comment: so the iOS simulator will always alert the message 'Couldn't access webcam'? Or only when it's not properly set up (even though it won't be able to use the built-in imac camera)?

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like this feature to be added, may I suggest you post a feature request at https://bugreport.apple.com/ . I think it's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've submitted a feature request. maybe you would like to do the same? and anyone else who feels like it might be a good idea? Guessing the more people who request such a feature the more likely apple are to acknowledge the request.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want to rewrite a lot of the AVFoundation framework for the Simulator environment.    Currently, even the symbols aren't there.